# Is there a reason to do a second trial if you got 7 wins on your first?

Tags: legends-of-runeterra

I just played my first Expeditions run in Legends of Runeterra and was lucky enough to get 7 wins. I still get the option to do my second trial, but since 7 is the most possible, is there any reason to? Will I get more rewards if I get 7 wins again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Expeditions you get rewards based on your highest number of wins, so playing the second trial will only get you some more XP per game.